# Model First Entity Framework connection string error "Initialization string begin with 0 "

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-4, connection-string

I'm building an ASP.NET web app with an Entity Framework model first DAL.
I've two VS project:

- a class library with the designed model
- an ASP.NET Web Application.

In the class library EF generated for me the folowing connection string:

```
    <add name="DatabaseModelContainer" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DAL.DatabaseModel.csdl|res://*/DAL.DatabaseModel.ssdl|res://*/DAL.DatabaseModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=NBK179\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=TaskBoardTest;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;"providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

It works in the class library project but when i paste it in the web app and try to use it with a EntityDataSource a get this error:

```
[ArgumentException: Formato della stringa di inizializzazione non conforme alla specifica che inizia all'indice 0.]
   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.GetKeyValuePair(String connectionString, Int32 currentPosition, StringBuilder buffer, Boolean useOdbcRules, String& keyname, String& keyvalue) +5081160
   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Hashtable parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean firstKey) +132
   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean useOdbcRules) +98
   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.ChangeConnectionString(String newConnectionString) +118
   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection..ctor(String connectionString) +81
   System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.CreateEntityConnection(String connectionString) +42
   System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext..ctor(String connectionString) +12
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.EntityDataSourceView.ConstructContext() +467
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.EntityDataSourceView.ExecuteSelect(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments) +76
   System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback) +21
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect() +143
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind() +74
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.DataBind() +4
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound() +66
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeDataBoundControl.CreateChildControls() +75
   System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls() +102
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +42
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +175
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +175
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2496
```

My code:

**Asp.net Page:**

```
<asp:EntityDataSource runat="server" 
ID="applicationDataSource" 
ConnectionString="DatabaseModelContainer" 
DefaultContainerName="DatabaseModelContainer" 
EnableFlattening="true" ></asp:EntityDataSource>
```

**Web.config**

```
<add name="DatabaseModelContainer" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DAL.DatabaseModel.csdl|res://*/DAL.DatabaseModel.ssdl|res://*/DAL.DatabaseModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=NBK179\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=TaskBoardTest;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;"providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

How can I solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `ConnectionString="name=DatabaseModelContainer"`